# Qt C++ widgets of GUI displayed differently in size, position etc on different Computers

Tags: c++, qt, widget, display

I have a problem concerning the appearance of my GUI:

On my computer where I develop my GUI all Widgets in the GUI are set OK in size, position etc. But when I use the GUI on different computers I have problems on some of them: The widgets are very small, captions are larger than the widgets, the position of the widgets is different.

**Is this a problem of my code using (or not using) size Policy?**  Do I have to set this property for each and every widget ? Can I do this for my whole GUI only once in a central place like the constructor...?

**Or is this a problem of the machine where My GUI is used on?** Something like monitor resolution, Windows-Version, etc...

Thank you for your help

Comment: You *need* to show your code.  Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Different OSs have different sizes of their fonts, window decorations/content, dpi-settings and themes. You are supposed to deal with that by putting your widgets into layouts which will then automatically get positioned and resized to fit. If you hardcoded the positions and sizes that will only work for one setting.

Comment: Additionally, one very tricky part is when dealing with HiDPI resolutions and scale factors (SF): macOS on Retina displays sets SF=2x, and Windows 10 many times has SF=1.25x. This affects the size of text but usually not the position of widgets.

Comment: Which development tools and OS do you use? Qt version?

Comment: I use Qt Creator 2.8.1 , Qt 4.8.4  , Win7, 64 bit

Comment: @nwp is right. If you want more detailed answers you should give the configuration of both computers (OS including version, screen resolution and dpi, etc.), a minimal example of your code (.cpp and .ui) exhibiting the problem. Also may I suggest to upgrade to Qt 4.8.7, it is fully forward and backward compatible with Qt 4.8.4 but with less bugs.